# How can I use the following code with php?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I use the following code with php?

```
var life=parseFloat(this.hp)/parseFloat(this.maxhp);
document.getElementById('life2').style.width=Math.round(1+106*life)+"px";
addEvent(document.getElementById('life1'),'mouseover',function (e) {
    if(!e)var e=window.event;
    tip.show(e.clientX,e.clientY,'','<B>Punkty życia:</B>'+hero.hp+'/'+hero.maxhp);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert this javascript to php? You can't; it's client-side. Are you trying have a php-rendered page have javascript on it? Just put an `echo` and script tag around the whole thing.

Comment: @AutumnLeonard i want do compatible in serverside with this client side but i don't know how i can use the $_POST and $_GET to clientside work

Comment: If you want to use $_GET or $_POST data to influence what mouseover shows, you could dynamically change whether you echo a `:hover` CSS.

Comment: @AutumnLeonard do you mean <div id=life1> echo ".$some['hp']."; ?

Comment: Your question needs a lot of clarification, and it looks like maybe you should learn some more PHP basics.